# Not able to click the HTML Modal pop up Cancel button in protractor test case

Tags: angular, protractor

I have the application that will load the Modal pop while loading the application page.

in the below format the application loads the 2 module.

For Example :

```
           <app-component></app=component>
           <modal-popup></modal-popup>
```

i am writing the below protractor test case in app.e2e.spec.ts

```
fit('should display app component', () => {
page.navigateTo(); // will navigate to app component page
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
   const condition = EC.and(EC.textToBePresentInElement(element(by.css('.navbar-brand')), 'appcomponent'));
browser.wait(condition, 5000);
});

fit('should click cancel', async () => {
/*  const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
 const okButton = element(by.buttonText('Cancel'));
 browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(okButton), 5000);
 okButton.click(); */ ----- > solution did not work
element(by.cssContainingText('.acat-btn-secondary cancel-btn', 'Cancel')).isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {
  if (isDisplayed) {
    element(by.css('acat-btn-secondary cancel-btn')).click(); //to close the alert
  }
});
});
```

Cancel Button HTML:

```
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="btn-container">
          <button type="button" class="acat-btn-primary submit-btn"
                                [disabled]="cycleSelected? false : true"
                                (click)="HandleUserSelectionOk()">Ok  
          </button>
          <button type="button" (click)="closeUserSelectionModal()"
                                class="acat-btn-secondary cancel-btn">Cancel
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Every time i run the test case the pop gets displayed with the cancel button but the test case fails with below error.

```
  × should click cancel
  - Failed: No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText(".acat-btn-secondary cancel-btn", "Cancel")
```

Can anyone please suggest how to overcome this test case failure?

Comment: can you share how the cancel button html element looks like? we can't really help without that information

Comment: @JoaquinCasco added the cancel button html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should modify both element locators. Try this:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.acat-btn-secondary.cancel-btn', 'Cancel')).isDisplayed().then(function (displayed) {
  if (displayed) {
    element(by.css('.acat-btn-secondary.cancel-btn')).click(); //to close the alert
  }
});
```

Btw, it seems unnecessary to go with `cssContainingText` in the first one, you could use `by.css('.acat-btn-secondary.cancel-btn')` for both.
I also modified the `isDisplayed` parameter you were passing, always try to use different keywords because you can easily make mistakes when you have the `isDisplayed()` function named like the parameters.

Comment: this is not working consistently. it breaks with below error: Failed: element click intercepted: Element <button _ngcontent-c7="" class="acat-btn-secondary cancel-btn" type="button">...</button> is not clickable at point (901, 362). Other element would receive the click: <button _ngcontent-c7="" class="acat-btn-secondary cancel-btn" type="button">...</button>